# BC: How to add a dataset and modify a report from 'base microsoft' with a 100xx ID?

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-al

I am trying to modify a report that is given by base microsoft and I can't figure out how to 'replace' and add a dataset the 10081 report.

I have tried copying the report and modifying it, but I need to add a dataset and don't have access to the al code due to it being a base microsoft report.
I tried to make a new report, it just wont appear when I try and got o the returns. When I try to replace the 10081 report with the custom 5014x report it gives me an odd error like 'textbox billtity needs to be named billtocity' even though it is. I have also included the '=First(... , 'dataset') in the expresssion

Any youtube links, links to documentation or anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have tried to copy only the object of the report (the SSRS Report Builder object .RDLC), now, try to go into the object designer and try also to copy the code in AL, when you'll have also the code, you can modify it as you want.
Let me know.